# I want to make a custom login page for a Drupal 7 installation without using the tokens

Tags: html, authentication, drupal-7

Here's the scenario: I made a Drupal site, with permission for 'view published content-->Registered users' (because I want only registered users to view the content). so, the homepage (login page) actually is an 'access denied' page with login block in it's content area. This is making errors in Google Webmaster Tools homepage index. The homepage for a new unregistered visitor is an access denied page.

So I thought of firing the login action through a custom made HTML login form by using `action="<!--URL of login page"-->`

Is there any option similar to mentioned below ? (the below mentioned code is just opening the login page after hitting submit. I want a code that will successfully perform the login operation)

`<form action="http://siteURL/user/login" method="post">
E-mail<input type="text" name="name" value=""></input> <br>
Password<input type="password" name="pass" value=""></input> <br>
Remember me <input type="checkBox" name="rememberMe" checked><br>
<input type="submit" value="Login"></input>
</form>`

Comment: Now I am using a "Redirect 403 to Login" module. Now, when I fetch the homepage (www.example.com) through Google Webmaster Tools, it says "Redirected". How can I get a complete successful fetch keeping the "view content" permission only for registered users?

Answer (score 1):

I think that your problem could be solved using the [Views Module](https://www.drupal.org/project/views). You could create a page in views and set the URL of your new view to the home page at Administer -> Site configuration -> Site information

Additionally if you ever feel the need to edit a theme output, you can override the template files -> https://www.drupal.org/node/173880